# Mason JAVA JDTLS Neovim

Tags: neovim, language-server-protocol, mason

I am trying to configure JAVA lsp with my Neovim Config [My Neovim Config](https://github.com/JonEasy/NeovimConfig/tree/master)

I have used Mason to install JDTLS among other LSP's as well, see below:

[image]

My lspconfig has the following form:

[image]

My LSP servers all work fine except for Java. When inspecting the lsp logs I get :
[image]

Comment: Isn't the error clear enough? There is something wrong with argparse and jdtls, go find the issue. There is nothing related to neovim based on the error message.

Comment: I did use https://github.com/eruizc-dev/jdtls-launcher to install jdtls. Not sure what is wrong in there.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my experience, JDTLS has a different way to attach as compared to other LSP. You have to refer to [the original jdtls documentation](https://github.com/mfussenegger/nvim-jdtls) to setup the server.

You can attempt this setup (based on the docs above I linked)

[image]

See if it helps you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. That link requires Java 17?

Comment: if you follow their original configurations then yeah, it requires java 17, the documentation includes what you should do if you have a different java version. As I am currently developing with Java 17 I don't have additional issues / need for additional config

Comment: I am using java 11 but will give it a try. Thanks